# unable to merge pr to master after a successful build via jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, github, groovy

```
sh 'git config --global user.name "$ghprbTriggerAuthor"'  
    sh 'git config --global user.email "$ghprbTriggerAuthorEmail"'  
    checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm:
      [$class                           : 'GitSCM',
       branches                         : [[name: sha1]],
       doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
       extensions                       : [[$class : 'PreBuildMerge',
                                            options: [mergeStrategy: 'DEFAULT', fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF', mergeRemote: 'origin', mergeTarget: 'master']]],
       submoduleCfg                     : [],
       userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: '<id>', url: 'git@git.xx.com:<repo-name>/<project-name>',name: 'origin',
        refspec: '+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*',]]]
        sshagent (credentials: ['<credentialId>']) {
           sh "git status"
           sh "git push origin master"

        }
        sh 'git log -n 10'
```

### jenkin shows  logs as below:

> git checkout -f cf1dbfbd9e1f52bf41738884a5c48ab1a59e5104
>       [Pipeline] sshagent

```
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-eAaXoe8YpGdR/agent.28743
SSH_AGENT_PID=28746

[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Search-UI] Running shell script
+ git status
HEAD detached at origin/master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
[Pipeline] sh
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 28746 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[Search-UI] Running shell script
+ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

but unable see any changes on git. Is there anything else I need to configure

Answer (score 0):

```
  options: [mergeStrategy: 'DEFAULT', fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF', mergeRemote: 'origin', mergeTarget: ghprbTargetBranch]]]
```

You have mentioned mergeTarget as **"ghprbTargetBranch"**

> mergeTarget is the branch you wish to merge with.

and

```
 sh "git push origin $ghprbTargetBranch"
```

The above two commands aren't matching... you might have mistakenly added the $ in the above command.

If not, then you have mentioned $ghprbTargetBranch i.e. it can/could have a value assigned to it like so 
ghprbTargetBranch = master

Based on the logs I'm guessing you are trying to merge to master. If that's the case then you need to change **mergeTarget to master**.

If not, i.e. **mergeTarget= ghprbTargetBranch** is the branch that you wish to merge to, then
the sh command i.e. $ghprbTargetBranch (value assigned to it is not ghprbTargetBranch)is probably different.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: hey, thanks for you answer 'ghprbTargetBranch' is the parameter only which has value master  mergeTarget= master only

Comment: Did it work ?? then you will have to change `mergeTarget=master` or `mergeTarget=$ghprbTargetBranch`

Comment: Change both values to master i.e. hardcode it to master and try... also add an `sh "git status"`

Comment: > git show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 483616f569c9a7499669a323e00e4856473ee448 (origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 483616f569c9a7499669a323e00e4856473ee448
Commit message: "Merge commit 'eb244fe03afb2110d4f2f5cb3085079ee4b42969' into HEAD"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Search-UI] Running shell script
+ git push origin master

[Search-UI] Running shell script
+ git status
HEAD detached from origin/master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: add the git status before the push

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer as below:

```
sshagent(credentials: ['<credentialId>']) {
              sh 'git checkout master'
              sh 'git merge --no-ff $sha1'
              sh 'git push origin master'
            }
```